How do I take this 2D integral of an exponential function that has a truncation?
I have a 2D distribution that goes like  $f(x,y) = exp(-\frac{x^2 +y^2}{v_t^2})$

that I want to truncate at a given radius away from the origin. The truncation line has the form $y(x) = \frac{x^2 - a^2}{2a}$. 
My initial thoughts were to slap on a Heaviside function onto the distribution so that it has the form  $f(x,y) = exp(-\frac{x^2 +y^2}{v_t^2})\cdot H(y - y_c(x))$ 
where $y_c(x)$ is the truncation I mentioned before. I have not been able to integrate this in all real space to get a solution using wolfram/mathematica. I was hoping someone could help solve this or at least reformulate the problem so that I can hopefully get clean-ish solutions. Ideally, I would be able to take integrals of the form $\int x\cdot f dxdy$, $\int x^2 \cdot f dxdy$, and other basic moments of this form (y, $y^2$, etc). Thank you, I appreciate any help.
